# How to popup or error message when no checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

If no `checkbox` is selected for different `employeeID`, show a popup or error message when user click on submit button. How can I do this?

Below is the part of `Employee.jsp` page code, which is a table of **different** employee records:

```xml
 <s:iterator value="employeeList">
       <td><s:checkbox name="employeeListID" fieldValue="%{employeeID}" theme="simple" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{employeeID}" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{employeeName}" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{mobileNo}" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{employeeLocation}" /></td>
    
 </s:iterator>

<s:submit id="submitEmployee" value="Register" theme="simple"></s:submit>
```

Comment: so what i think you are asking is.. if checkbox with the name employeeListID is not selected when user hits submit, show error?

Comment: ya.. but I want to do this with javascript

Comment: is this wrapped in a form? if so does the form have an id?

Comment: yes this is wrapped in a form id "myform"

Answer (score 1):

Use a required field validator which checks if the specified field is not `null`.

```xml
<field name="employeeListID">
    <field-validator type="required">
           <message>no checkbox is selected</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById('myform'),
    checkBox = document.getElementsByTagName('input').employeeListID;

function validateForm(){
    if(!checkBox.checked){
        alert('Please Check the Checkbox');
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}

formElement.addEventListener('onsubmit', validateForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `validate()` methods.

```
  private String employeeListID; //Getter & Setter Method.

  private void validate(){
      if (employeeListID==null) {
          addActionError("Please Select CheckBox.");
      }
  }
```